# Trying to make an application which downloads content from a web page

Tags: android, web

I would like to write an application that notifies me whenever a class has opened up. A a naiive way would be to download the HTML source code and look for a particular string that indicates "open" (For open classes) or "waitlist" (waitlist is open) then notify me. How should I approach this? I've looked into HTPClient but it makes it more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) is a java based HTML parser that may be useful for you. However ideally you'd want to get access to some API that exposes just the data that you are interested in, rather than relying on HTML parsing. At some point (sooner rather than later generally) the HTML will change and break your app because it will have to make assumptions about the HTML that will get changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple HTML parser worked for me.